# Selenium w/ Chrome v74 on Linux .NET Core (DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Tags: c#

Ever since the latest Chromium update I have been unable to run Selenium on Linux (.NET Core)

Google Chrome is installed on `usr/bin/google-chrome`, and I have made sure of it as I have ran it directly from the directory it's stored in.

```cs
Starting ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}) on port 32911
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.

Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-45-generic x86_64)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at selenium.Program.Main() in REDACTED
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have tried disabling shm, use headless mode, and other recent issues on this topic, but none have worked.

```cs
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("--headless --no-sandbox");
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.images", 2);

            IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, options);

            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"file:///login.html");
```

The expected output is for ChromeDriver not to throw an exception and crash.

Comment: Make sure the ChromeDriver version matches the Chromium version installed on your machine. I had the same error when using ChromeDriver for 76 while having Chromium 75 installed.